# "Algorithm negotiation fail" with SSH authentication on TeamCity

Tags: git, ssh, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

We have a TeamCity 7.1.5 and our Git Repositories are hosted on a TFS 2017. We wanted to switch to SSH authentication with a Public/Private key. So I have created an openSSH keypair and added the public key on my TFS user. On my local machine this works as expected.

But when I want to configure my TeamCity VCS Root to use SSH as well, I always get the following exception:

```
Failed for the root 'VCS ROOT' #830: List remote refs failed: 
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
```

The private key is available on the TeamCity server and the `config` should be correct:

```
Host tfs.company.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/tfs.company.com_rsa_sha1
```

I have tried both `Default Private Key` and `Private Key` options, with and without passphrase.

The only thing I found is to upgrade the `JSch` library, but I couln't figure out how to upgrade this library and where to put the jar file.

Does anyone have similar issues or know how to upgrade the library?

Comment: Algorithms in SSH is not only public key. There are more. You can investgate them from command line ssh very simply, but I believe you will be able to get some debug also from the jsch. First of all, I would try updating the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously the solution was very simple. I just needed to download the newest version `0.1.54` of the JSch library from http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ and put it into `C:\Program Files\TeamCity\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib`. Restart TeamCity and everything works.