# List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail

Tags: github, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

After GitHub "has disabled support for weak encryption" [ https://githubengineering.com/crypto-deprecation-notice/ ]  in [ https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows ] my TeamCity lost connection with Git:

> "List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm
>   negotiation fail"

I had a update Github in server/slaves and changed register entries. And, I tried update jsch lib to last "jsch-0.1.54.jar" [ ["Algorithm negotiation fail" with SSH authentication on TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781559/algorithm-negotiation-fail-with-ssh-authentication-on-teamcity) ], but doesn't works.

My env:

- Teamcity Professional 8.1.4 (build 30168)
- Windows 2008 Server R2 x64
- Git version 2.16.1.windows. (x64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue (I was on `9.0.1`, however), upgrading to `jsch-0.1.54.jar` did not help either.

Ended up upgrading to version `10.0.3` and that fixed everything. Upgrading is very simple.

1. Download the `.tar.gz` of the specified version you want to upgrade to
2. Copy your current `server.xml`
3. Untar the file somewhere on your server where you want it to sit
4. Paste the `server.xml` configuration into the new version under `conf/`
5. Restart the TeamCity process (if you're using something like `systemd` to manage the process)

If not using `systemd` or some other similar daemon manager, just launch the process however you normally launch it.

Comment: Hi Narek, thanks in advance. I tried with this version but just the erro changed 
to: "List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out "

Comment: Can you post some additional information here like VCS settings?

Comment: Hi Narek, all worked. The connection issue was resolved! Thks!